# How do I fill the contents of a 2-dimensional array, whose dimensions are input by the user, with the contents of another 2-dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

In the following homework assignment:

1. Create an array of 100 random numbers in the range of 1…999, write a function for each of the following processes. In building the array, if 3 or 7 evenly divide the random number, store it as a negative number.

a.       Print the array ten values to a line. Make sure that the values are aligned in rows.
b.      Return a count of the number of even values
c.       Return the sum of all values in the array

2. Create a two dimensional array (size 10 X 10). Fill this two dimensional array with the values from the above single dimensional array. Determine the maximum value in each row.  Display the two-dimensional array and the maximum of each row.

***3. Repeat number 2 above but this time instead of 10 X 10 array, prompt the user for the size of the row and column, allow user to fill in the values and display the array.(Hint: Use pointers and dynamic memory allocation )***

I'm stuck on number 3. I'm not sure how to correctly use the dynamic memory allocation and pointers to make room for the number of rows and columns the user inputs.

```
int main(void)
{
int hundred[100];
cien(hundred);
even(hundred);
total(hundred);
two_dim(hundred, table);
hi_row(table);
cust_arr(hundred,table);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
void cien(int hundred[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int range = (999 - 1) + 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        hundred[i] = rand() % range + 1;
        if (hundred[i] % 3 == 0 || hundred[i] % 7 == 0)
        {
            hundred[i] = hundred[i] * -1;
            printf("%d\t", hundred[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d\t", hundred[i]);
        }

    }
    return;
}

int two_dim(int hundred[], int arr[][10])
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int i = 0;
    int table[10][10];
    while (i != 100)
    {
        for (x = 0; x <10; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                arr[x][y] = hundred[i];
                printf("%d\t", arr[x][y]);
                i++;
            }
        }

    }
    return **table;
}

void** cust_arr(int hundred[], int table[][10])
{
    int x, y, i, j, k=0;
    int **arr;
    printf("input the number of rows.\n" );
    scanf_s("%d", &x);
    i = (int*)calloc(x, sizeof(int*));
    printf("input the number of columns.\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &y);
    j = (int*)calloc(y, sizeof(int*));
    while (k != 100)
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= x; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= y; j++)
            {
                hundred[k] = table[10][10];
                table[10][10] = **arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", **arr[i][j]);
        k++;
    }
}
```

Since the prompt says to repeat number 2, I have tried to make similar loops in my cust_arr() function

Answer (score 0):

malloc will return a pointer the the memory region allocated. You can use brackets on pointers to specify an index just like static arrays. Since you need a 2d array, you need a pointer pointing to an array of pointers i.e. the columns point to the rows, the rows point to the values.

```
int ** dynamicPointer = malloc(sizeof(int*)*columns);
for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
   dynamicPointer[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*rows);
//address of final column and row
dynamicPointer[columns- 1][rows  - 1] = 3;
print("%d\n", dynamicPointer[columns- 1][rows  - 1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

For 10x10 array I would suggest using [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). If you want to use [dynamic allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) then use `malloc` function.

```
int x, y;
int **table;

scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
table = malloc(x*sizeof(int *));
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    table[i] = malloc(y*sizeof(int));
```

Beside this, the code shown has many flaws and need to be fixed. Better to put all the function declaration and definition outside the function with specifying their return type and parameters.